# DatabaseError: table OmniCloud_App_user has no column named username

Tags: python, django, sqlite, terminal

So I got this when trying to add a User to the database. And I thought, I wonder what columns it does have? So I asked for the sql...

```
DatabaseError: table OmniCloud_App_user has no column named username
>>> 
root@Harold:~/OmniCloud/omnicloud# python manage.py sql OmniCloud_App
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "OmniCloud_App_user" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "email" varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    "username" varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    "password" varchar(30) NOT NULL
)
;
```

Hey! There it is! Why would it get mad at the two following lines if it seems to, in fact, have said column?

```
>>> u = User(email="gmail@gmail.com", username="gmail", password="gmail")
>>> u.save()
```

Also not how I am defining a User class and it says that `user` has no column called username. Why does it go lowercase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Have you run a `$> python manage.py syncdb`?
- Have you changed the model (added the username) since you first ran syncdb?
- Are you using South? If not, you should probably learn about it.

Syncdb only works on new models. You've got to sort out migrations yourself, and that's where South comes in.

Alternatively, you can modify the database on your own, or use another app, which is closer to that method, called nashvegas.

This is an approximation of the SQL that you need.

```
ALTER TABLE OmniCloud_App_user ADD COLUMN "username" varchar(25) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: South is working wonderfully. I did have to migrate and your advice was very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`manage.py sql` gives the SQL that the table *would* have if you asked `syncdb` to create it now. It doesn't show you what the table *actually* has - for that you're going to have to go into your db shell and ask it to describe the table for you. Then, you'll need to modify it, either directly there or via a migration tool like South.