# Connect to User Model in Django

Tags: python, django, models

Quick (probably foolish) question. This is the flow of my site: User logs in and is redirected to a custom admin page. On this admin page they have the ability to make a 'Profile'. I want to associate the Profile they create with their User data such that 1 User associates to 1 Profile.

For some reason the following isn't working (simply trying to associate

**UserAdmin.Models**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

**UserAdmin.Views**

```
def createprofile(request):

    user = User.objects.get(id=1)
    profile = Profile(username=user, firstname='Joe', lastname='Soe', email='Joe@Soe.com')
    profile.save()
```

I keep getting: **table useradmin_profile has no column named username_id**

Any ideas? Appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Deleted my db and ran a fresh syncdb, changed to username = models.OneToOneField(User). Now I cam getting **Cannot assign "u'superuser'": "Profile.username" must be a "User" instance.**

Comment: You might be interested in [How to Extend Django User Model](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UserAdmin.Models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()
```

UserAdmin.Views

```
def createprofile(request):

    user_ = User.objects.get(pk=1)
    profile = Profile(user=user_)
    profile.user.first_name = 'Joe'
    profile.user.last_name = 'Soe'
    profile.user.email = 'Joe@Soe.com'
    profile.user.save()
    profile.save()
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Now I am getting: Cannot assign "u'John'": "Profile.username" must be a "User" instance. (John is a User.username)

Comment: Edited the code... Try that. You will have to do a fresh syncdb though.

Comment: Hmm. Okay tried that with a fresh syncdb. The shell is printing out a blank when I try to access print a.first_name where a = User. When I try to access the Profile object and do Profile.objects.all() I get [<Profile: >] printed instead of full_name(). Any ideas?

Comment: Yes to I have that in the view, tried it with and without that line. Still not creating Profile properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You syncdb'ed the Profile model before you had a `username` ForeignKey field. Django will only create tables but will not alter them once they have been created. Here an answer listing your options: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7693297/990224.

And you should think about renaming `username` to `user`.

Comment: Deleting the db and doing a fresh syncdb did not solve the problem, as expressed in the other answer.

Comment: Well, you have to decide whether you want to save the username or a User. What `Cannot assign "u'superuser'": "Profile.username" must be a "User" instance` tells you is that you're trying to save the username in Profile.username. But Profile.username must be a user. So either pass on the user or change your OneToOneField to a CharField.